# What happens when two paranthesis are next to each other with no operant in between?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to use ctypes to run a c-lib using python and couln't get it to run exactly how I want.
So I did some research and came across this:

> args = (c_char_p * 3)(b'abc', b'def', b'ghi')

I never saw anything similar and would like to find out what it does. Sadly, I don't even know what to search for.

Comment: If `c_char_p * 3` evaluates to a callable, then this simply calls whatever callable it is with three arguments.

Comment: It is for arrays, in the example a intermediate variable `TenIntegers` is used: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#arrays

Comment: Thank you two, i got more insight. Still, I couldn't wrap my head around. What does the left and the right part do and how do they come together? I would think it is two tupples, but then there is no operator in between so I am lost ...

Comment: `f = c_char_p * 3; f(b'abc', b'def', b'ghi')` — Does that make sense? Then what you show is the same thing, just rolled into one expression without intermediate variable.

Comment: this made it way better to follow, now I understand the TenIntegers...
I think so if this is correct:
we create a callable f (basically an array, right?) with 3 "arguments/values" and after assign the bytestrings to those "arguments/slots"?

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @deceze, this question was answered.
Seeing it written like this, it is kinda self-explanatory:

> f = c_char_p * 3; f(b'abc', b'def', b'ghi')

"If c_char_p * 3 evaluates to a callable, then this simply calls whatever callable it is with three arguments" -deceze